# Why this strange behavior in Spark randomSplit API?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
val df = Seq(("x", "y", 1),("x", "z", 2),("x", "a", 4), ("x", "a", 5), ("t", "y", 1), ("t", "y2", 6), ("t", "y3", 3), ("t", "y4", 5)).toDF("F1", "F2", "F3")

+---+---+---+
| F1| F2| F3|
+---+---+---+
|  x|  y|  1|
|  x|  z|  2|
|  x|  a|  4|
|  x|  a|  5|
|  t|  y|  1|
|  t| y2|  6|
|  t| y3|  3|
|  t| y4|  5|
+---+---+---+
```

I am trying to create a test train split of this dataframe. I have observed a strange behavior in the process as follows:

Following code works:

```
val Array(train_DF, test_DF) = df.randomSplit(Array(0.6, 0.4), 1234L)
```

But why the following code does not work?

```
val Array(Train_DF, Test_DF) = df.randomSplit(Array(0.6, 0.4), 1234L)
```

It gave an error as follows:

```
<console>:25: error: not found: value Train_DF
       val Array(Train_DF, Test_DF) = df.randomSplit(Array(0.6, 0.4), 1234L)
                 ^
<console>:25: error: not found: value Test_DF
       val Array(Train_DF, Test_DF) = df.randomSplit(Array(0.6, 0.4), 1234L)
                           ^
```

> Is the dataframe name inside Array case sensitive?

Comment: Thanks @sailesh. That was the dupe I was looking for.

Comment: mainly, the reason for this failure is how pattern matching works in Scala. On the other hand, `val (Train_DF, Test_DF) = ...` should also work